# Laravel 5.4 If statements with auth conditions on it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

The problem is it gives an error.

Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$confirmed

Here's my code:

```
if (Auth::guard('pharmacy')->confirmed == 1) {


    if (Auth::guard('pharmacy')->status == 'Approved') {


        return redirect()->intended(route('pharmacy.dashboard'));

      }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have `confirmed` in your user table?

Comment: yes . They're all called in the controller from my model .

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```
if (Auth::guard('pharmacy')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    if (Auth::user()->confirmed == 1 && Auth::user()->status == 'Approved') {
        return redirect()->intended(route('pharmacy.dashboard'));
    }
    //You might want to do something else here for those that fail either the confirmed or approved check.
}
```

First, you should authenticate the user against the `pharmacy` guard instance. It is only when the user has been authenticated that you can now have access to his/her `attributes`...in your case...`confirmed` and `status`.

Comment: I have tried the following code and it shows an error "Trying to get property 'confirmed' of non-object" .

Comment: Ok... Do `dd(Auth::check())` after the first line... What have you got?

Comment: Hi again , it says "Trying to get property 'confirmed' of non-object".
And also i did a dd after the first if execution it says false .

Comment: Do you have a `pharmacy guard` set in your `config/auth.php` file?

Comment: Yes ,         
'guards' => [
'pharmacy' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'pharmacy',
        ],
],

'providers' => [

'pharmacy' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Pharmacy::class,
        ],

    ],

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you table has the field `confirmed` and you've registered the guard properly to use that table as the provider.

**Guard**: `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [

   // ...

   'pharmacy' => [
      'driver' => 'session',
      'provider' => 'pharmacies',
   ],
],
```

**Migration**

```
class CreatePharmaciesTable extends Migration
{
   public function up()
   {
      Schema::create('pharmacies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // ...
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
      });
   }

   // ...

}
```